# I need a very good dynamic random number generator

Tags: random-number-generator

I am doing research and I need a RNG (preferably an API) which generates very good numbers dynamically, or provides the exact date/time the number was generated.

I have looked at the [ANU Quantum RNG](http://qrng.anu.edu.au) which would fit the bill perfectly but I am unsure if the number is generated dynamically on each API call or it just comes from a pool of previously calculated numbers. Unfortunately they don't answer my emails.

Comment: What OS/language should it be compatible with? How much would you pay if needed?

Comment: Any API is fine. I know that random.org charges a fee and we may do that if we can't get a solution. But we are doing very far-out research so I hope that we can get a very random number generator which is generated real-time. The fact that the ANU RNG is based on quantum fluctuations is the perfect randomness.

Comment: Do you need *truly random* numbers, or pseudo-random, in a repeating sequence? For truly random, you might use lavarand, e.g., https://blog.cloudflare.com/randomness-101-lavarand-in-production/